# How to determine quadrant given x- and y-coordinate columns in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, where-clause

Dataframe format:

| tooth_id | x_center | y_center | width | height | quadrant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.309643 | 0.082520 | 0.072325 | 0.169476 |  |
| 2 | -0.211200 | -0.057675 | 0.071321 | 0.199645 |  |
| 3 | -0.307634 | -0.127773 | 0.081366 | 0.187223 |  |
| 4 | -0.262933 | -0.093611 | 0.065294 | 0.211180 |  |
| 5 | 0.253139 | 0.136646 | 0.096936 | 0.190772 |  |

Question: how to write a loop to deliver the following outcome?
In each roll:

```
if x_center >=0 and y_center >= 0, quadrant = 1
if x_center <0 and y_center >= 0,  quadrant = 2 
if x_center <0 and y_center <0,    quadrant = 3
if x_center >0 and y_center <0,    quadrant = 4
```

Comment: Note: your quadrant conditions don't fully encompass the cartesian plane: points where `x == 0` and `y < 0` aren't captured by this logic. You should change q4's logic to `x >= 0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

Here's another solution, using `arctan2` and a little modular arithmetic. Note that Corralien's approach is much more generalizable. What follows is very specific to this use-case.

```py
import numpy as np

deg = np.round(180 * np.arctan2(df.y_center, df.x_center) / np.pi).astype(int)
df["quadrant"] = 1 + ((deg + 360) % 360) // 90
```

Output:

```py
>>> df
   tooth_id  x_center  y_center     width    height  quadrant
0         1  0.309643  0.082520  0.072325  0.169476         1
1         2 -0.211200 -0.057675  0.071321  0.199645         3
2         3 -0.307634 -0.127773  0.081366  0.187223         3
3         4 -0.262933 -0.093611  0.065294  0.211180         3
4         5  0.253139  0.136646  0.096936  0.190772         1
```

Note, points on the axes are "rolled over" into the neighboring quadrant in the anti-clockwise direction, e.g., the point `(0, 0.631)`, which lies at 90° is considered quadrant 2; `(-0.578, 0)`, which lies at 180° is considered quadrant 3, etc.

### Steps

Use `np.arctan2()` to get the angle (in degrees) formed by each `(x, y)` point:

```py
>>> deg = np.round(180 * np.arctan2(df.y_center, df.x_center) / np.pi).astype(int)
>>> deg
0     15
1   -165
2   -157
3   -160
4     28
dtype: int32
```

Now, convert `(-180°, 180°]` to `[0°, 360°)`:

```py
>>> deg = (deg + 360) % 360
>>> deg
0     15
1    195
2    203
3    200
4     28
dtype: int32
```

Floor divide by 90 to get the quadrant (which'll return 0, 1, 2, 3 -- so also add 1):

```py
>>> quadrant = 1 + (deg // 90)
>>> quadrant
0    1
1    3
2    3
3    3
4    1
dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
# Update: change 'df.x_center > 0' to 'df.x_center >= 0'
# See comment of @ddejohn below

df['quadrant'] = np.select([(df.x_center >= 0) & (df.y_center >= 0),
                            (df.x_center < 0) & (df.y_center >= 0),
                            (df.x_center < 0) & (df.y_center < 0),
                            (df.x_center >= 0) & (df.y_center < 0)],
                           choicelist=[1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   tooth_id  x_center  y_center     width    height  quadrant
0         1  0.309643  0.082520  0.072325  0.169476         1
1         2 -0.211200 -0.057675  0.071321  0.199645         3
2         3 -0.307634 -0.127773  0.081366  0.187223         3
3         4 -0.262933 -0.093611  0.065294  0.211180         3
4         5  0.253139  0.136646  0.096936  0.190772         1
```